# USB to COM for WIndows XP

Tags: windows-xp, usb, serial-port, com

Basically, I recently purchased a customer display for my EPOS till which runs on Windows XP (Yes I know XP Is old but it is running some legacy software). Anyways, in the Epson OPOS my display appears as just an USB device and whilst I did install the virtual COM for this device I have had no luck configuring it.

Does anyone know of anyway of assigning the USB customer display to say a COM4 port? Or even just converting it such that it works for a COM port?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you just use the USB port on the computer?  Or, if XP Desktop, add a USB card?

Comment: @John yeah the customer display has a USB cable which I have connected to the XP machine via a USB port. I have even installed the drivers and it works fine. BUt it does not work on the EPOS software because the OPOS utility requires the devices to be connected to a COM port

Comment: I looked at my XP machine here and did not see a way to connect the USB to a COM port. Different devices.

Comment: @John appreciate you looking into this, like what I meant was whether there was a way of converting the USB into a virtual COM PORT?